# Xamarin firebase message to run intent while application in closed state

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin

I need to update my SQLite database with details sent via an online MVC application which sends a firebase data message to the Xamarin Application linked to the specific user's profile
While the app is in the foreground I can update the database directly with the details contained within the firebase data message.

The problem is that I need the database to be updated whilst the application is in a closed state so when they open it the UI and data states are already built and ready for the user (Without having to then do an HTTP request to get any new information)

Through my workings, I have seen that I must use a Firebase.Jobdispatcher...however I see that it seems to have been deprecated.

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
{
    base.OnMessageReceived(message);

    //Custom message received
    if (IsApplicationInTheBackground())
    {         
        //The send notification sends the push notification no problem 
        SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Body, message.Data);

        //I wish to add specific code to write to the SQLite here 

    } else
    {
        //Notify within the application using snackbar
        var mA = new MessageAndroid();
        mA.ShortAlert(message.GetNotification().Body);

        var uti = new FindMyDriver();    //Location pin pointing request
        uti.ReturnLocationAsync(message.GetNotification().Body);

    }    
}
```

In the block where it states "I wish to add specific code .." I would like to save specific details about the loads that have been sent from the MVC application to the linked user App on a registered phone.

I would like to call a specific void to run whilst the App is offline/background.

Is this at all possible with all the controls on services etc lately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big issue above was that the FCM didn't actually fire the OnMessageReceived event.
This was due to the FCM being received as a notification and not as a data payload. Once I changed the payload to data it worked 100% allowing me to initialize a foreground service and run from there.